# Store True as 1 False as 0 using Laravel + Eloquent + Mysql

Tags: laravel

I have a value of `true` or `false` coming from an ajax post to the back end (laravel) and I want to store it as `1` or `0` in the mysql database. This is basically a checkbox or radio that I reach into the `DOM` and grab the value. I believe I should be able to add a mutator:

```
protected $casts = [
    'active' => 'boolean',
];
```

This does pull the `1` and convert it to `true`, however it does not store `true` as `1`.

The documentation does not say the cast will be performed both directions for `boolean`, however it does say the cast works both directions for `array`

> Once the cast is defined, you may access the options attribute and it will automatically be deserialized from JSON into a PHP array. When you set the value of the options attribute, the given array will automatically be serialized back into JSON for storage:

I could convert to integer on the client, I guess I would prefer to do it on the back end. Any other thoughts? I will need this conversion on many tables. I am using laravel 5.2

Answer (score 0):

I believe you only need to be sure that your database column type is either boolean or tinyint.

Edit:

However, you can use a Mutator function in you model in order to convert it to int, like the following:

```
public function setActiveAttribute($value)
{
    $this->attributes['active'] = (int) $value;
}
```

Comment: It is: $table->boolean('active'); From mysql: active  tinyint(1)

Comment: OK it looks like you need both, we arrived at the same conclusion. It is way less code for me to send over a 0/1 from the client...